# Java Generics PECS , add capture ? super cannot be applied to java.util.list

Tags: java, generics, collections, consumer, contravariance

The issue of variance (particularly contravariance) has got me banging my head against the wall for a week. I have finally understood the theory, thanks to a couple of questions on here, and now as soon as I start working on it, I am getting errors I just don't understand.

I have a simple heirarchy of classes:

abstract class Fruit,
Mango extends Fruit,
Orange extends Fruit,
BloodOrange extends Orange

```
abstract class Fruit implements PlantEatable {

    private boolean isRipe;

    private boolean isEatable;

    public boolean isRipe() {
        return isRipe;
    }

    public void setRipe(boolean ripe) {
        isRipe = ripe;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEatable() {
        return isEatable;
    }

    public void setEatable(boolean eatable) {
        isEatable = eatable;
    }
}

public class Mango extends Fruit {

}

public class Orange extends Fruit{

}

public class BloodOrange extends Orange{

}
```

Now, The Oracle documentation generally has been great about Generics except for the part that was the most important I find confusing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html

If I am doing PECS which is Producer Extends Consumer Super

I am trying to do something very simple:

```
public class UpperBoundEg {

    public static <E> void copy(List<? extends E> src, List<? super E> dest) {
        src.forEach( item -> {
            dest.add(item);
            System.out.println("Added to dest: " + item.getClass());
        });
    }

    public static <E> void acceptTest(List<? super Orange> objects) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Producer
        List<? extends Orange> oranges = new ArrayList<>();
        //oranges.add(new Orange()); // Doesn't work because its a producer ?

        //Consumer
        List<? super BloodOrange> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(new BloodOrange());
        //objects.add(new Orange()); // Why doesn't it work ?
        //objects.add(new Object()); // Why doesn't it work ?

        copy(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Orange(),
                        new Orange(),
                        new BloodOrange(),
                        new Object(), 
                        new Mango() // Why is this allowed?
                ),
                new ArrayList<>()
        );

    }
}
```

Why is this happenning ? I thought List<? super BloodOrange> should take BloodOrange and all its super classes ?
Why is it only accepting BloodOrange ?

And Why am I able to add a Mango to the copy function ?

[image: Adding super types to consumer objects, throws error?]

Comment: Because a `List<? super BloodOrange>` may actually be a `List<BloodOrange>`, and so it's an error to add anything to it that is not a `BloodOrange` (i.e., an instance of the class itself or a subclass).

Comment: It may make more sense if you had `void populate(List<? super BloodOrange> list) { ... }` and then called `populate` with an instance of `List<BloodOrange>`. The call to the method will succeed, and that setup should help you see why adding anything other than `BloodOrange` to `list` is an error.

Comment: Okay, Im just confused because what I read was <? super T> means that type and any super class of that, so I just thought it should be accepted. Aah!!! Maybe i just had a light bulb moment, does this mean a single collection can only have one type ? When we say List<? super T> someList, does that mean someList can be a list of T or a super type of T, but not the same list which has all the super types ?? I am really sorry about the silly question

Comment: Does this mean say if I have List<? super BloodOrange> that means I can pass to it a List<BloodOrange>, List<Orange>, List<Object> ? But I can't create a single List of type <? super BloodOrange> with all kinds of BloodOranges, Oranges and Objects in the same list ? This would answer everything

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate, but you may find some helpful information among the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```java
> List<? extends Orange> oranges = new ArrayList<>();
> oranges.add(new Orange()); // Doesn't work because its a producer ?
> ```

You seem to think a `List<? extends Orange> oranges` means: The list referred to by the variable named `oranges` can contain 'anything that is either an Orange, or some subtype of it'.

**But that is wrong**.

After all, if that's what you wanted, you would just write `List<Orange>`. Given:

```
BloodOrange a = new BloodOrange();
Orange b = a; // this is, obviously, legal.
```

The type of the `b` variable is `Orange`, but the object it is pointing at, is actually a BloodOrange. Which is fine. All bloodoranges are oranges. But, therefore, obviously:

```
BloodOrange a = new BloodOrange();
Orange b = a;
List<Orange> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(b); // this.. has to be legal!
list.add(a); // it would be ridiculous if this wasn't, then!
```

The above compiles completely fine. I just added a bloodorange to a `List<Orange>`. Which, of course, I can do: **All BloodOranges are Oranges**. So why wouldn't I be able to?

Hence, for the meaning 'a list that contain anything that is either an Orange or some subtype of it', `List<Orange>` is it. Not `List<? extends Orange>`.

`List<? extends Orange>` has a different meaning. It means:

*This is a list that is restricted to contain.. I don't actually know. It has some, unknown to this code, restriction. However, what I do is, that the nature of the restriction is either that it can only contain Oranges (and therefore, BloodOranges are also fine), or, some subtype of Orange.*

In other words, this is legal:

```
List<BloodOrange> bloodOranges = new ArrayList<BloodOrange>();
List<? extends Orange> someSortOfOrangesList = bloodOranges;
```

and now you see why you can't call `.add(new Orange())` on a `List<? extends Orange>`. After all, java is reference based, the above code contains only one `new` statement **so there is just one list, period**. You merely have 2 variables that both point at the same list - it's like having an address book with 2 separate pages both listing the same address - that doesn't magically mean there are now somehow 2 houses. So, if you add something to `someSortOfOrangesList`, you're also adding it to the list pointed at by variable `bloodOranges`, given that both variables are pointing at the same list. Thus, if you COULD add `.add(new Orange())` to a `List<? extends Orange>`, then I just added a NOT BloodOrange to a list whose type is `List<BloodOrange>` and I just broke it. Hence why the compiler won't let you, at all.

Once you understand this, all is clear:

> ```java
> List<? super BloodOrange> objects = new ArrayList<>();
> objects.add(new BloodOrange());
>        //objects.add(new Orange()); // Why doesn't it work ?
>        //objects.add(new Object()); // Why doesn't it work ?
> ```

Same reason: `List<? super BloodOrange>` does not mean 'this list can contain bloodoranges or any supertype of it'. Because that's completely pointless - if you want that, just write `List<Object>`. No, it means: "This List has some unknown to be restriction, however, I do know, that restriction is either BloodOrange, or Orange, or Fruit, or Object. One of those 4, I don't know which one, but.. it has to be one of those 4 or the compiler wouldn't have allowed me to write the assignment".

And with that specific restriction, you CAN add BloodOrange instances to this list. Because `.add(new BloodOrange())` is fine on a `List<Orange>`, it is also fine on a `List<BloodOrange>`, and also fine on a `List<Fruit>`, and also fine on a `List<Object>`. We know it has to be one of those 4, so it is fine.

You can't call `.add(new Orange())` on this list because that is fine for 3 of the 4 things it could be, but not if your `List<? super BloodOrange>` variable is pointing at a list whose type is `List<BloodOrange>`. Because then you'd be adding a not-BloodOrange to it, we don't want that.

> ```java
> copy(
>                Arrays.asList(
>                        new Orange(),
>                        new Orange(),
>                        new BloodOrange(),
>                        new Object(), 
>                        new Mango() // Why is this allowed?
>                ),
>                new ArrayList<>()
> ```

Because java will figure out that picking `Object` as a bound works here. Because they're all objects.

A crucial thing you need to understand here is that `class Foo extends Bar` means: "Any instance of Foo is just as suitable as a Bar and can be used anytime, anywhere, a Bar is required; the reverse is not necessarily true of course", therefore, they are ALL objects and can ALL be used where an `Object` would be required. Thus, java goes: Aight, we'll make that `E` bound to Object, turning it into requiring [A] `List<? extends Object>` and [B] a `List<? super Object>` - and `List<Object>` fits both of those bounds. So, we interpret the `List.asList(...)` as `List.<Object>asList(...)` which is fine as every argument to it is an object (all things are objects, so that's obvious then), and we'll interpret `new ArrayList<>()` as `new ArrayList<Object>()` and voila that will compile just fine. Hence, that's what happens here.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I can't believe it took so long to get it. So basically Does this mean say if I have List<? super BloodOrange> that means I can pass to it a List<BloodOrange>, List<Orange>, List<Object> ? But I can't create a single List of type <? super BloodOrange> with all kinds of BloodOranges, Oranges and Objects in the same list ?  And the same would apply in reverse if it was <? extends Orange> ?

Comment: Very well put. This should be a canonical answer for questions of this type.

Comment: _ that means I can pass to it a List<BloodOrange>, List<Orange>, List<Object> ?_ - no - generics are invariant. If a method requires a `List<Orange>`, then only a `List<Orange>` will do. Or an `ArrayList<Orange>`, but no other list. Generally it's method params that use `? extends` or `? super` to allow callers to be more flexible. You don't ever write `new ArrayList<? super BloodOrange>()` - that is useless, the super/extends stuff is for types of params in methods.

Comment: PECS says: Producer extends, Consumer super. If you user neither super nor extends, then you're saying: This method both consumes _and_ produces (and therefore only this exact thing will do). A method that takes a `List<Orange>` both has the intent to add oranges to the list _and_ read objects from it, and treat them as oranges. (Which is why only `List<Orange>` will do. It's the only one that can do both).

Comment: Just one addendum. Immutable lists can’t subvert the type safety, as their `add` methods will throw an exception unconditionally. Therefore, they allow type transitions not covered by the rules above. E.g. `List<BloodOrange> bloodOranges = new ArrayList<BloodOrange>(); List<Orange> orangesListView = Collections.unmodifiableList(bloodOranges);` So when you have a `List<? super BloodOrange>` its actual element type might be one of the four mentioned types (five, actually, `PlantEatable` is possible too) *or* it might be an immutable list in which case the actual element type becomes meaningless.