# Java Generics: collection with same lower bound cannot be added to another collection with the same lower bound

Tags: java, generics

Not able to understand why this is disallowed.

```
List<? super Number> numList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3.0, "hello");  
List<? super Number> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(1);
numList.addAll(l); // <----- Error Here
```

The Error Description:

```
'addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends capture<? super java.lang.Number>>)' in 'java.util.List' cannot be applied to '(java.util.List<capture<? super java.lang.Number>>)'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Generics PECS , add capture ? super cannot be applied to java.util.list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75667328/java-generics-pecs-add-capture-super-cannot-be-applied-to-java-util-list)

Comment: [See this answer from rzwitserloot for a terrific explanation of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75667524/2985643). It is one of the best written answers I have seen on SO on any subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounded wildcard `? super Number` represents some type that is a supertype of `Number`. However, it's unknown what specific type that is, so two different wildcards of the same bounds could refer to different types.

For instance, `numList` could be a `List<Number>` and `l` could be a `List<Object>` (both of which are valid because `Object` and `Number` satisfy the wildcard). In this case, it is clear that you cannot add arbitrary `Object`s to a `List` of `Number`s.